# How to run WebView2 with browser flags?

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, webview2

I'm using the class [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.webview2?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#definition) to host web content.

I want my web view to host the web content through a browser instance ran with flags/switches (e.g. `--disable-auto-reload`).

I searched the documentation I linked above but I couldn't find how to do this, even though it should be possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a current limitation of the WinUI2 and WinUI3 WebView2 control. It does not have a way for the caller to provide a custom CoreWebView2Environment to use (unlike the WPF and WinForms WebView2 controls). I'd recommend bringing this up on [the related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1170).

As a workaround, you might try setting the `WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS` environment variable to `--disable-auto-reload` in your own process before creating the WebView2. See the [documentation for this environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl?view=webview2-1.0.1293.44#createcorewebview2environmentwithoptions) for more information.